# Entity Framework não converte INTEGER do Firebird para long do C#

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

Estou fazendo alguns testes com Entity Framework mapeando e migrando uma base de dados de um sistema legado.

**Cenário**

Onde tenho uma tabela similar a isso:

```
TESTE
-------------------------------------- 
ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
NOME   VARCHAR(100),
ATIVO  SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
--------------------------------------
```

E em meu modelo isso:

```
public class Teste: BaseModel
{
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Ativo { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Sendo que meu mapeamento Fluent seria isso:

```
var testeMapper = modelBuilder.Entity<Teste>().ToTable("TESTE");
testeMapper.HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
testeMapper.Property(x => x.Nome).HasColumnName("NOME");
testeMapper.Property(x => x.Ativo).HasColumnName("ATIVO");
```

**Problema**

Ao executar uma simples consulta nessa tabela, sou surpreendido com o seguinte erro:

> `The type of the key field 'Id' is expected to be 'System.Int64', but the value provided is actually of type 'System.Int32'`.

Que pelo que entendi é porque estou utilizando `long`(`System.Int64`) no modelo e minha base de dados a coluna é do tipo `INTEGER` (que ele considera `System.Int32`). O que não parece fazer muito sentido, pois o `System.Int32` facilmente pode ser setado em um `System.Int64` (O contrario já não seria bem assim).

Sei que:

1. Se trocar o tipo do atributo `Id` no meu modelo para `int` (`System.Int32`) irá funcionar;
2. Se trocar o tipo da coluna `ID` para `BIGINT` (que ele considera `System.Int64`) também irá funcionar;

Só que essas duas opções não seriam viáveis para o meu caso, pois:

1. O Atributo `Id` do tipo `long` está na `class` `BaseModel` que é uma convenção do sistema, e é `long` pois as novas tabelas estão sendo criadas com `ID` `BIGINT`. Para contorno isso o modelo não poderia herdar de `BaseModel`, o que não seria a melhor opção.
2. A coluna ID daria uma grande manutenção para serem convertidas para `BIGINT`, pois tem `contraints` e `PKs` ligadas a ela o que dificulta o trabalho.

**Pergunta**

1. Há alguma forma de desligar essa verificação do EntityFramework?
2. Ou há alguma configuração que permita que o modelo e tabela continue desta maneira?

Answer (score 1):

Mude a sua classe `BaseModel` para [Generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/512aeb7t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), veja abaixo:

```
public class BaseModel<T>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

na sua classe:

```
public class Teste: BaseModel<int> // ou long
{
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
```

As regras para mapeaar os dados para [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) são restritiva ao tipo de dado dos campos da **Tabela**, que não seria lógico ser diferente, se na sua tabela está com `INTEGER` o dado na `classe` é `int`([Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) e ser for `BigInt`([Int64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int64(v=vs.110).aspx)), se as próximas tabelas serão com [BigInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int64(v=vs.110).aspx) a `classe` `BaseModel` com um tipo [Generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/512aeb7t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) soluciona esse problema de tipo.

No [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) não tem como *desligar a verificação*, isso é interno e na minha visão seria um grande **erro**, traria mais problemas do que solução, já que ele segue as normas estabelecidas nas configurações da tabela.

Então, reafirmando, faça um `BaseModel<T>` [Generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/512aeb7t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) que possa ter `int` ou `long` como **paramentro de tipo**, e não influenciando em si as configurações de sua base de dados legada.

> Log Gerado `INSERT`:

---

> Para ID to tipo int ou INT32

```
Closed connection at 13/09/2016 20:52:24 -03:00    
Opened connection at 13/09/2016 20:52:24 -03:00    
Started transaction at 13/09/2016 20:52:24 -03:00

EXECUTE BLOCK ( p0 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET UTF8 = @p0 )  
  RETURNS ("ID" INT) AS BEGIN INSERT INTO "CLIENTE"("NOME") 
  VALUES (:p0) RETURNING "ID" INTO :"ID"; SUSPEND; END

-- @p0: 'BAB' (Type = String, Size = 50)    
-- Executing at 13/09/2016 20:52:24 -03:00    
-- Completed in 21 ms with result: FbDataReader    
Committed transaction at 13/09/2016 20:52:24 -03:00    
Closed connection at 13/09/2016 20:52:24 -03:00
```

Nesse trecho, observe que ele manda um paramento do tipo `String` de tamanho **50** para a tabela.

```
-- @p0: 'BAB' (Type = String, Size = 50)
```

e nesse

```
RETURNS ("ID" INT)
```

o tipo de retorno da `ID` é `int`.

> Para ID do tipo `long` ou `Int64`

```
Closed connection at 13/09/2016 20:59:53 -03:00
Opened connection at 13/09/2016 20:59:53 -03:00
Started transaction at 13/09/2016 20:59:53 -03:00

EXECUTE BLOCK (
p0 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET UTF8 = @p0
) RETURNS (
"ID" BIGINT)
AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO "GENTE"("NOME")
VALUES (:p0)
RETURNING "ID" INTO :"ID";
SUSPEND;
END

-- @p0: 'abc' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- Executing at 13/09/2016 20:59:53 -03:00
-- Completed in 16 ms with result: FbDataReader
Committed transaction at 13/09/2016 20:59:53 -03:00
Closed connection at 13/09/2016 20:59:53 -03:00
```

nesse caso o

```
RETURNS ("ID" BIGINT)
```

o **ID** é do tipo `BIGINT` `(Int64)`

---

***Referencias:***

- [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)
- [Estrutura Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Estrutura Int64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int64(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Introdução aos genéricos (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0x6a29h6.aspx)
- [Genéricos (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

***Observação:*** o **modificador** [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), não é necessário em todas as propriedades, só em *coleções* e *agregação* para [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)

Comment: Certo entendi sua alternativa e já estou implementando aqui em meus testes, e parece funcionar de acordo. Só mais uma duvida, pelo que entendi do funcionamento dessa verificação ele faz uma consulta nos metadados da tabela e verifica se os tipos são correspondentes. E isso não pode ser desativado para produção? Para evitar _overhead_ nas consulta? Acredito que isso só ocorra ao iniciar o Context, mas mesmo assim isso parece desnecessário para ambiente de produção!

Comment: Ele usa padrões e tipos correspondente entre banco e classes, na hora do insert ele envia o tipo e pode ocorrer erros na tradução. Até a versão 6.1.3 ele funciona assim, particular do ORM. NUNCA vi configuração para desativar, em lugar nenhum, sinceramente acho eu que não tem. Vou gerar um Log do Insert, e adicionar na resposta, logo que entra no pc estou no cel.

Comment: @Fernando eu coloque os dois logs um com insert do tipo de ID `int` e o outro `Long`. é na hora do `Insert, Update e Delete` ele manda paramentos para o banco que possui tipos e ai que o problema pode ocorrer se não for o respectivo. Na verdade o provider do Firebird instalado é quem faz essa geração de SQL.